# class 'domdocument' not found laravel when sending email

Tags: php, laravel, web, domdocument

I am trying to send verification mail to user using mail system

```
Mail::to($thisUser->email)->send(new varifyEmail($thisUser));
```

but it gives me

```
Class 'DOMDocument' not found
```

this is the function that gives this error

```
protected function createDomDocumentFromHtml($html)
{
    $document = new \DOMDocument('1.0', 'UTF-8'); // this is the line with error
    $internalErrors = libxml_use_internal_errors(true);
    $document->loadHTML(mb_convert_encoding($html, 'HTML-ENTITIES', 'UTF-8'));
    libxml_use_internal_errors($internalErrors);
    $document->formatOutput = true;

    return $document;
}
```

can anyone help for this??

Comment: did you installed dom extension?

Comment: yes, of course .

Answer (score 3):

### You have to install the [DOM extension](http://www.php.net/en/dom)

#### If you are using PHP 7:**

- For Ubuntu:**

  ```
  apt-get install php7.0-xml
  ```
- For CentOS / Fedora / Red Hat:**

  ```
  yum install php70w-xml
  ```
- Restart your web server

Comment: @AnaJentel check your php version and install xml for that perticular php version

Comment: Also, remember to restart the web server after installation.